# How do I play music using CSS?

Tags: css, audio, html

How do I make music play when my page loads using CSS?

I need music to automatically play and have controls for it.

Comment: That's not what CSS is for. Try JavaScript...

Comment: You just cannot with only CSS you will need Javascript

Comment: I hate it when websites do that...

Comment: For people saying "try/need/use JavaScript": Why do you "need JavaScript"? How can one "use JavaScript" for this? Where in the ECMAScript specification is "audio" or "sound" defined? (Hint: It isn't. Something *besides* JavaScript is required, even if there are nice JavaScript libraries which *are wrappers* to mechanisms to play audio.)

Answer (score 7):

Music is content. CSS is presentation, not content.

You can embed audio in HTML:

```
<audio src="path/to/song.mp3" controls autoplay></audio>
```

This is minimal, though, so it won't work in Firefox for instance since it doesn't support MP3. There are tutorials for this.

Comment: As alluded to, that same markup works perfectly well in Firefox if you encode the file as "song.ogg"

Comment: I think one could argue that music *can be* used as presentation (as background ambiance music might be no more "content" than a background image). However, CSS covers the display aspects of presentation *only*, so..

Comment: @pst Actually CSS can be used to define how screen-readers should read stuff, so it is used for audio to some extent... just not like this.

Comment: I think better define, should add the word "visual" representation, otherwise, images are content too, and the attribute `content` is content also!

Answer (score 4):

You can use html5 audio tag, taken from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp) , note which browsers are supported.

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

If you need to support IE8 and below consider using [jplayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) which has flash fallback when html5 audio is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, this is not natively possible with CSS. Your only options are HTML5, JavaScript, Applets or 3rd party technologies like Flash and SilverLight. However, each of these options have their own caveats and flaws.

1. HTML5 is not fully supported by all browsers, and will result in your page / site not having a non-consistent experience - which you wouldn't want.
2. Javascript is probably your best bet as it is for the most part cross-browser except for text-only browers, or very lite browsers (which you may find on some earlier generation cellphones).
3. Applets are a separate can of worms in themselves as you will have to deal with another programming language (and all its nuances), as well as the ***horribly annoying*** matter of your users having to activate the applet every time they visit or refresh the page.
4. Flash or Silverlight is another promising alternative as they can run in any browser - provided that the operating system supports it. However, the visitors of your site / page have to have that plugin installed and enabled. If you decided to go this route, Flash is the best option as almost every computer and OS runs and supports it. However, one thing to note is that of late (past 5 years or so), Adobe has been having some security issues with Flash.

Thus, my suggestion would be:

1. Javascript - particularly Jquery.
2. HTML5 if you can - but supported by Javascript as a backup. Example: http://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/
3. Flash / SilverLight and like technologies.
4. Applets

And for a Hodgepodge of possible ways of how to do this you can visit this link:  A nice collection to start is this one: http://iapdesign.com/webdev/25-awesome-html5-and-jquery-plugin-music-player/

Comment: How does "sound in JavaScript" work *without* one of the other options? Where is `jQuery.playSound`? And, assuming correct use of a "sound plugin", how *would* it work?

Comment: Agreed @pst. There isn't a pure native JavaScript / jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Gif that plays on hover using CSS. I have the MP3 file to match the Gif animation. Can some code be added within the CSS hover section that would trigger the audio file in the HTML code you have so they play at the same time?

*CSS:*

```
.animation:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('my_animation.gif'), url('Background.jpg');
 **ADD some code here to trigger my_sound.mp3**
}
```

*HTML:*

```
<audio autoplay>
  <source src="my_sound.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think so there is no css code. try to use this html code

```html
<audio controls="controls" autoplay>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```